# Could not find com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.1.0 in FLUTTER

Tags: android, flutter, dependencies, build.gradle

I'm pretty new to flutter,i cloned an working flutter application from Github which is a Text to speech app using transcription something.After cloning I followed these steps,

> flutter pub get

> flutter upgrade

After doing these steps,I thought of running the flutter  by connecting my android device(I already used this host android device for many testing),but it throws error as

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>   Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.1.0.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>   - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/1.1.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.1.0.pom
>   - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/1.1.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.1.0.jar
>   Required by:
>   project : > com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0

Below code is my project level gradle file code,

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
}
```

You can request any other files for reference,Please help me,this is my starting stage of building an APP,a more way to go,Thanks in Advance!

[Edited] My pubspec.yaml file is ,

```
name: fluttr_protorecorder
description: A new flutter project.
version: 0.2.0
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/sytody.png
```

Comment: Can you provide the Github repo link?

Comment: https://github.com/rxlabz/sytody, though it's a bit old version Android,it says Androidx missing like that